# how to get a value from jdropdown menu?

Tags: java, drop-down-menu

I have a set of list from a Java drop down menu? how do I get the value of the drop down menu once I have selected one item from the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get it from the object dropdown: `String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();`

More examples can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html